# Use ParametricNDSolve with Plotting

Tags: differential-equations, vector, parametric-functions

I am attempting to solve a differential equation of the form 
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=ax+by \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=cx $$ with parameters $0<a<1$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. I am able to use NDParametric Solve, but would like to generate a stream vector plot of the solutions, with $a=\lbrace 0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0 \rbrace$ b and c as the x-axis and y-axis. I can solve for varying values of $a$, but how do I turn this into a stream vector plot?

Comment: Could you please post your code for the `NDParametric Solve`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @user21807 for a, b, c constants the system is linear and has a simple analytic solution. Why not take that?

Answer (score 4):

As has been observed by Dr. Wolfgang Hintze if a,b and c are constant this coupled system has easily derived analytic solutions. In general, this site strongly encourages you to try to present your attempts and then focused clear guidance can be given. I post this as in this case this does not really require more than 'out of the box' functions. Perhaps it can be illustrative and motivate your own play:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[StreamPlot[{a x + b y, c y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], 
  ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
      First@DSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == {{a, b}, {0, c}}.{x[t], y[t]}, 
         x[0] == ix, y[0] == iy}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]], {t, 0, 10}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red] /. Line[w__] :> Arrow[w], 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{ix, iy}]}], {a, 0.01, 
  1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {ix, -3, 3}, {iy, -3, 3}]
```

I have not aimed for efficiency, terseness or clarity just coded on the run to motivate starting...

[image]

Comment: How do you go about creating that movie (GIF I suppose)?

Comment: @Amzoti apologies for delay in replying. I use http://licecap.en.softonic.com/ to  screen capture. You can can create animated gifs from Mathematica. There are a number of helpful  searchable posts on this site.

Comment: No problem - excellent +1, thanks.