# Trouble using ParametricNDSolve in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parameters

I have troubles to understand how to use `Manipulate` and `ParametricNDSolve` to have modulable parameters inside my models. I checked numerous questions on this forum and couldn't find one that satisfies my needs (or, more likely, I didn't understand what to do):

- [parametricNDSolve for solving differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188929/parametricndsolve-for-solving-differential-equation)
- [Use ParametricNDSolve with Plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76106/use-parametricndsolve-with-plotting)
- [Manipulating a Differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130346/manipulating-a-differential-equation)

In these examples, the parameters are defined in an equation that isn't a differential one. I don't know if it changes anything in my case but its seems to be at the origin of my problem.

Anyway, here is what I did:

First of all, I've got this model and these constants:

```
dEc = p1*Ec[t]*(1 - (Ec[t]/Emax)) - d1*Ec[t] - i1*Ic[t]*Ec[t] - r*Vu[t]*Ec[t];
dIc = i1*Ic[t]*Ec[t] + r*Vu[t]*Ec[t] - u1*Ic[t];
dVp = is[t]*b1*u1*Ic[t] - c1*Vp[t];
dUc = p2*Uc[t]*(1 - (Uc[t]/Umax)) - d2*Uc[t] - i2*Yc[t]*Uc[t] - e*Vp[t]*Uc[t];
dYc = i2*Yc[t]*Uc[t] + e*Vp[t]*Uc[t] - u2*Yc[t];
dVu = is[t]*b2*u2*Yc[t] - c2*Vu[t] + s*Vp[t];

parameters = {Emax ->   10000, Umax ->   10000000, p1 ->   0.6, d1 ->   0.003, d2 ->  0.006, u1 ->   0.33, u2 ->   0.33, c1 ->   10, c2 ->   1, b1 ->   6000, b2 ->  6000, i1 ->   0.0000002, i2 ->   0.0000001, e ->   0.000000001, r ->   0.0000001};
```

Please note that the parameters `p2` and `s`are not defined in the `parameters` list. It's because that's the ones I want to modify using `Manipulate`! These parameters are found in equations `dUc` and `dVu`

Then, I do a `ParametricNDSolve` on these equations:

```
dynamicsmodels =
 ParametricNDSolve[
  Evaluate[{
     Ec'[t] == dEc ,
      Ic'[t] == dIc ,
     Vp'[t] == dVp ,
     Uc'[t] == dUc ,
     Yc'[t] == dYc ,
     Vu'[t] == dVu , 
     Ec[0] == 10000, Ic[0] == 0, Vp[0] == 10, Uc[0] == 10000000, 
     Yc[0] == 0, Vu[0] == 0, is[0] == 0.0005,
      WhenEvent[t == 200, is[t] -> 0.0001]
     } /. parameters],
  {Ec[t], Ic[t], Vp[t], Uc[t], Yc[t], Vu[t]},
  {t, 0, 300},
  {p2, s},
  DiscreteVariables -> {is}[[1]]]
```

Please note that `is[t]` is a variable that evolves in the model following time (see my previous question: [Having trouble using WhenEvent with NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193049/having-trouble-using-whenevent-with-ndsolve)).

Then, I do a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   {
     Ec[p2, s][t],
     Ic[p2, s][t],
     Vp[p2, s][t],
     Uc[p2, s][t],
     Yc[p2, s][t],
     Vu[p2, s][t]
     } /. dynamicsmodels
   ], {t, 0, 300},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 300}, {0, 10000}},
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green, Blue, Purple, Orange},
  PlotLegends -> {"Ec", "Ic", "Vp", "Uc", "Yc", "Vu"}], 
 {p2, 1.2, 1.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {s , 1, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"} 
 ]
```

I don't have any error, but no lines either... Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: As it was asked in my previous question: this model refers to intra-host evolution of viruses, and it can be found here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1600-6143.2008.02402.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html):

```
pndsval = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  Evaluate[{Ec'[t] == dEc, Ic'[t] == dIc, Vp'[t] == dVp, 
     Uc'[t] == dUc, Yc'[t] == dYc, Vu'[t] == dVu, Ec[0] == 10000, 
     Ic[0] == 0, Vp[0] == 10, Uc[0] == 10000000, Yc[0] == 0, 
     Vu[0] == 0, is[0] == 0.0005, 
     WhenEvent[t == 200, is[t] -> 0.0001]} /. parameters], {Ec[t], 
   Ic[t], Vp[t], Uc[t], Yc[t], Vu[t]}, {t, 0, 300}, {p2, s}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {is}[[1]]]; 

 Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[pndsval[p2, s] /. t -> v], {v, 0, 300}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 300}, {0, 10000}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green, Blue, Purple, Orange}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Ec", "Ic", "Vp", "Uc", "Yc", "Vu"}], {p2, 1.2, 1.5,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {s, 1, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works pefectly well. Thanks a lot. I see that I need to improve my maths now!

Comment: @Jerobou, you are welcome. Thank you for the accept.